# Why is this HAVING COUNT(*) > n query so slow?

Tags: mysql

I have what I thought was a pretty simple query running on a simple index that's taking >4s to run. The query, which just returns 100 group_ids out of a total of 300 possible group_ids is just:

```
SELECT my_table.group_id FROM my_table GROUP BY group_id HAVING count(group_id) > 100;
```

The table is just:

```
my_table | CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `score` float NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `score2` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `score3` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `score4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score5` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score6` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `score7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_id` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uix_key1` (`name`,`group_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uix_key2` (`other_id`,`group_id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
  KEY `ix_my_table_score1` (`score1`),
  KEY `ix_my_table_score2` (`score2`),
  KEY `ix_my_table_score3` (`score3`),
  KEY `ix_my_table_score4` (`score4`),
  KEY `ix_my_table_score5` (`score5`),
  KEY `ix_my_table_score6` (`score6`),
  CONSTRAINT `my_table_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`group_id`) REFERENCES `groups` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4500000 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin
```

Doing an `EXPLAIN` shows the query is using the index it's supposed to use:

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT my_table.group_id FROM my_table GROUP BY group_id HAVING count(group_id) > 100;
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table          | partitions | type  | possible_keys                                                        | key             | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | data_set_items | NULL       | index | uix_name_group_id_id,uix_other_id_group_id,group_id                  | group_id        | 4       | NULL | 1727838 |   100.00 | Using index |
+----+-------------+----------------+------------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

This seems like it should be <1s. Any ideas?

To make things even weirder, when I change it to `COUNT(group_id) > 1` it goes even slower, which makes 0 sense to me.

Comment: try to run this query first and see how it perform : SELECT count(*) FROM my_table GROUP BY group_id

Comment: you can try rebuilding the table indexes by dumping and reloading it. Use mysqldump to create a dump file and mysql to reload the file:

Comment: why export and re-import when you can run commands like `analyze table` @dbmitch?

Comment: Note that any time you have enumerated columns (above '2', say), there's a fair chance that the design is flawed.

Comment: @Strawberry why's that, and how is it related to the question?

Comment: @dbmitch why would rebuilding the indexes help? I've never heard of needing to do that in MySQL. Have some more info about that?

Comment: @Eli - this thought occured to me when I saw your data rows sitting at 1.7 million rows. If they got to that number with many adds,deletes or edits of groupid, it might help to reindex

Comment: @Eli - it might just be that it's a problem you can't get arround with InnoDB format. Doesn't Innodb need to perform full table scan or full index scan, whereas I think MyISAM will get number of rows in the table from a stored value?

Comment: Because problems of poor performance often stem from poor design

Comment: @Strawberry when you say "enumerated columns" do you mean numerical  columns? Still have no idea how that would affect the performance of the query I asked about, (or why having them would be a bad idea design-wise, but that's beyond the score here anyway).

Comment: In a nutshell, and admittedly too concise a nutshell, SQL loves rows and hates columns.